# Primary key cardinality causing Partition Too Large errors?

Tags: cassandra

I'm inserting into a Cassandra 3.12 via the Python (DataStax) driver and CQL BatchStatements [1]. With a primary key that results in a small number of partitions (10-20) all works well, but data is not uniformly distributed across nodes.

If I include a high cardinality column, for example time or client IP in addition to date, the batch inserts result in a Partition Too Large error, even though the number of rows and the row length is the same.

Higher cardinality keys should result in more but smaller partitions. How does a key generating more partitions result in this error?

---

[1] Although everything I have read suggests that batch inserts can be an anti-pattern, with a batch covering only one partition, I still see the highest throughput compared to async or current inserts for this case.

---

`CREATE TABLE test
    (
        date date,
        time time,
        cid text,
        loc text,
        src text,
        dst text,
        size bigint,
        s_bytes bigint,
        d_bytes bigint,
        time_ms bigint,
        log text,
        PRIMARY KEY ((date, loc, cid), src, time, log)
     )
     WITH compression = { 'class' : 'LZ4Compressor' }
      AND compaction = {'compaction_window_size': '1',
                      'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS',
                      'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy'};`

Comment: What is the size of column that you did move into partition key?

Comment: @AlexOtt In the table above, replaced date (type date) with a timestamp type column. If I include both data and time columns I get the same issue. I referencing cardinality because the addition of time should result in many more partitions (because of resolution), but does not change row size. I don't believe I need that many partitions, but I'm trying to understand the relationship between the primary key and the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you meant `Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Batch too large` errors?

This is because of the parameter `batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb` which is by default 50kB of data in a single batch - and there are also warnings earlier at a at 5Kb threshold through `batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb` in cassandra.yml (see http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html).

Can you share your data model? Just adding a column doesnt mean the partition key to change - maybe you just changed the primary key only by adding a clustering column. Hint: `PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c,d)` uses only `a` as partition key, while  `PRIMARY KEY ((a,b),c,d)` uses `a,b` as partition key - an easy overlooked mistake.

Apart from that, the additional column takes some space - so you can easily hit the threshold now, just reduce the batch size so it does fit again into the limits. In general it's a good way to batch only upserts the affect a single partition as you mentioned. Also make use of async queries and make parallel requests to different coordinators to gain some more speed.

Comment: I will post the data model, but in this case I'm not adding columns, but moving one into the PK which has higher cardinality than the others. The row width remains the same.

Comment: Table added above.

Comment: The issue was indeed the size of the batch being inserted, not the size of the resulting partitions.